# Xamarin App Slow When Built On Xamarin.Android 6.1.x

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Our Xamarin app has much slower UI performance on Android when built using `mdtool` on a Mac vs. building using `MSBuild` on Windows 10.  E.g., rendering when changing orientation takes several seconds in the former case, but is almost instantaneous in the latter.  Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Note that it might not just be the UI performance that's improved; that's just what is most noticeable.

**Environment**

- Xamarin 4.0.3.214
- Xamarin.Android 6.0.3.5
- Xamarin Forms 2.1.0.6524
- Selected Architectures: armeabi-v7a

Comment: The code base (thus the compiler and resulting CIL) is the same assuming the same installed versions of `Xamarin.XXXXX` on both platforms. What `mdtool` options are you using and why not directly use `xbuild` (or the OS-X based `msbuild`) with the same Windows `msbuild` options? Also assuming you are testing on a physical device... have you binary diff'd the resulting assemblies? Disassembly the resulting assemblies and diff'd those?

Comment: Thx for the response. Not many options on the mdtool command: /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build -c:"Release" "MyApp.sln".  I believe the Mac has Xamarin.Android 6.0.2, which is slightly different from the 6.0.3.5 being used in the Windows build, but I wouldn't think a maintenance version would cause such a performance difference.  Not using xbuild or OS-X msbuild simply because we haven't gotten around to changing the scripts. Would that make a difference? I'll diff the assemblies.

Comment: You're right, SushiHangover: the cause was not building on Windows.  Our app seems to run much slower when built w/ Xamarin.Android 6.1.1.1 than with X.A 6.0.x.x.  We're trying to figure out why..

Comment: Our Android app is fast on X.A 6.0.4 and X.A 7.0.1.6, but not X.A 6.1.x.  Perhaps the Xamarin guys could explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have determined that the performance problem occurred when building on Xamarin.Android 6.1.x, but seems not to occur on X.A 6.0.x or X.A 7.0.1.6.  Building on Windows/Mac indeed did not matter, as SushiHangover suggested.

Perhaps the Xamarin folks could explain why this might be so.